# Using onclick="location... in place of href. Why I should avoid it and alternative options

Tags: javascript, html

We're using a CMS that provides a broken link report; however, that broken link report is useless to us because it detects some 1,300 links as broken because they are deep links into many different screens in our web app product. (I.e., a static HTML page links to a web app that requires authentication that our authoring tool can't process so it flags the link as broken - 404.)

Ideally, we'd be able to rely on the CMS reporting of broken links, and one thing I know works is to use an onclick event instead of an href. But I would like to know if there are reasons we should not do that.

Admittedly, I've read quite a few threads asking similar questions about onclick="function()", but they all seem a shade or two different from what we're trying to accomplish.

Is it okay to use an onclick event for these links instead of the standard href? (See code below.)

What problems or limitations would we encounter if we did? (For example, I'm not sure we'd be able to test if these onclick links actually work, at least not via automated link checkers, and that may be okay.)

Are there other options to have these links essentially skipped over by a broken link crawler/checker?

I'm looking for a better understanding of best practices here.

Thanks

```
<a href="[[relative path to web app]]" class="uxlink">Link Text</a>


<span onclick="location='[[relative path to web app]]'" class="uxlink">Link Text</span>
```

Comment: To me your trying to fix the wrong thing..  By using onclick you also loose the ability to right click the link and open in new tab, and I assume it's bad for those using screen readers etc.  To me the problem is your back end reporting 404, instead of 401.   401, would indicate to the crawler the page exits, but your not authorised, as such it's not a broken link.

Comment: I totally agree, @Keith! Thank you. A bit more info: 401 is returned when the content is published to its end destination, but the CMS and its source control feature don't have the ability to return any sort of custom http messages, which is a real bummer here. If I run a broken link crawler against my published output, I'll see 401s for those links. But in terms of the editorial workflow, it'd be better if we could catch the true 404 errors earlier in the process and not on publish (which would require a fix and then a re-build). Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: It sounds like the only point of switching to onclick redirects is to make your CMS's link checker skip over those links instead of trying to test them; could you instead configure your CMS to ignore internal links?  Or if it's not that configurable,  post-process its output to remove those internal links before passing it on to a human?  That would seem very preferable to degrading the user experience just to accommodate an inadequate link checker...

Comment: @DanielBeck you're spot on. It's a kludgy solution to a somewhat silly problem. Unfortunately, the CMS and its source control program aren't able to ignore a certain type of link. Could you elaborate on your second suggestion? By a post-processing step, are suggesting some sort of mark up flag in the CMS around these links and then a script or transform outside the CMS to build the links properly for the end user?

Comment: Yes, exactly that; if the CMS can't be configured and can't be modified, then instead of directly viewing the CMS's output, run a secondary script over it that will remove the lines matching relative paths, and view *its* output instead.    (And consider looking into replacing that CMS, but I'm sure you've thought of that already :)

Comment: Thanks, @DanielBeck! I'll investigate. I appreciate the help and advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onclick` breaks accessibility for screen readers. You need to add all your ARIA features manually. It also breaks SEO because crawlers can't follow the link.

Comment: Thank you! These are both important considerations, especially the one re: accessibility. As far as SEO goes, the entire site is also behind auth so it's not exposed to any public crawlers, but that's something for us to pay attention to because that could change down the road. Thanks again